# How to sort by previous date in database?

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to ask is how to select from database record and my php code able to sort previous date by date,which is what i want to display in my interface:

```
2011-10-01

2011-10-01

2011-10-01

something here..


2011-10-02

2011-10-02

something here..


2011-10-03

something here..
```

in my database some previous date got a lot duplicate date and some are only one record, so I need to sort it for make my interface more clear

here is my code(but it's not work):

```
$Current = date("Y-m-d" ,strtotime("now"));

$query= mysql_query("SELECT date FROM staff WHERE date < '$Current'");
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo $res['date'];
echo "something here";
}
```

thanks

Comment: did u try adding order by to your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simply use this?

```
SELECT `date` FROM staff WHERE `date` < NOW() ORDER BY `date`
```

or (if you need only different dates)

```
SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM staff WHERE `date` < NOW() ORDER BY `date`
```

Comment: Problem with distinct is that he will not get a count, and his required output shows he repeats the same date multiple times before writing his custom line. With distinct, you will not know what that count is.

Comment: @Andrew: you're right on SQL, but believe me, I find hard to understand what OP really wants/asks...

Comment: thank for comment, it sort by my date, but how to separate the previous date by display different table row ? example: 2011-10-01
in one table row, 2011-10-02 in another table row

Comment: @user1035140: I beg your pardon, but I really don't understand what you're trying to have as result. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

```
("SELECT count(*), date FROM staff WHERE date < '$Current' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date asc");
```

Group them up with a count, you can then write out each date the number of times indicated by the count, then write out your additional value.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want can be achieved by sorting the results in the db and removing duplicates by grouping

```
SELECT date FROM staff WHERE date < '$Current' ORDER BY date ASC GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Grouped dates (equivalent to distinct) means that the OP will not know how many times to repeat a date in his output - he shows the same date being printed multiple times, so he has to have a count of the dates, if they get grouped / distinct.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, I was a bit unsure about what was required. Thought I'd add this to show a method for grouping by date.

Answer (score 0):

the code you need is a very simple one.
you just have to understand the meaning of the loop and "remember" state between iterations

```
//a variable to remember the old date
$olddate = '';
//i named this variable $sql because it actually contains an sql query
$sql = "SELECT date FROM staff WHERE date < '$Current'";
//I named this variable $res because it actually contains NOT sql query, but mysql RESource.
$res = mysql_query($sql) or treigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
//I named this variable $row because it actually represents a row from the database.
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  if ($olddate and $olddate != $row['date']) {
    echo "something here";
  }
  echo $row['date'];
  $olddate = $row['date'];
}
```