# How to sort and add my database record?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort by previous date in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048844/how-to-sort-by-previous-date-in-database)

I want to do is select from mysql which is previous date records then from my database records I need to add the amount which is sort by date

my database records:

```
amount | date
2.0    | 2011-10-01
1.4    | 2011-10-02
2.6    | 2011-10-01
2.3    | 2011-10-02
4.4    | 2011-10-01
5.6    | 2011-10-03
6.3    | 2011-10-01
```

What I want to display in my interface:

```
amount | date
2.0    | 2011-10-01
2.6    | 2011-10-01
4.4    | 2011-10-01
6.3    | 2011-10-01
---------------------------
15.3   | 2011-10-01


1.4    | 2011-10-02  
2.3    | 2011-10-02
----------------------------
3.7    | 2011-10-02


5.6    | 2011-10-03
----------------------------
5.6    | 2011-10-03
```

my code (it not work):

```
$Current = date("Y-m-d" ,strtotime("now"));
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * from item where date < $Current order by date");     
    while($re=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $total = $total + $re['amount'];
    echo $re['date'];
    }
```

Isn't this can work nicely ?

thanks

Comment: This can be done by querying the database with aggregation functions, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into MySQL's [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) option.

Something like this

```
SELECT date,amount,item_id FROM table GROUP BY date,item_id WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can query for each date you wanna show

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE date = @date;
```

2) You can query for all the dates, and query for the totals

-- table rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < @date ORDER BY date;
```

-- table totals:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE date < @date GROUP BY date ;
```

You could do 2nd option in just one query, but the performance would be quite worse:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE date < @date GROUP BY DATE) AS total FROM table WHERE date < @date ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: then rate my answer ass possitive, or even the solution :)

Comment: "ass positive" is somewhat ambiguous %)

Answer (score 0):

You want to retrieve and display all those records anyway, don't you? Then:
In your php script you can store the last date it "handled". If the next record has another date value the current "group" is finished -> print the current sum, reset it to zero and store the new date. Print the current record, increase $sum by `amount`. Repeat until there are no more records.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

$prevDate = null;
$sum = 0;
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM soFoo WHERE `date`<CURDATE() ORDER BY `date`', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
    if ( $prevDate!=$row['date'] ) {
        if ( !is_null($prevDate) ) {
            echo "-----------------\n", $sum, ' | ', $prevDate, "\n\n";
            $sum = 0;
        }
        $prevDate=$row['date'];
    }

    echo $row['amount'], ' | ', $row['date'], "\n";
    $sum += $row['amount'];
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
        id int auto_increment,
        amount Decimal(8,1),
        `date` Date,
        primary key(id)
    )');
    $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO soFoo (amount,`date`) VALUES
        (2.0, '2011-10-01'),
        (1.4, '2011-10-02'),
        (2.6, '2011-10-01'),
        (2.3, '2011-10-02'),
        (4.4, '2011-10-01'),
        (5.6, '2011-10-03'),
        (6.3, '2011-10-01')
    ");
}
```

prints

```
2.0 | 2011-10-01
2.6 | 2011-10-01
4.4 | 2011-10-01
6.3 | 2011-10-01
-----------------
15.3 | 2011-10-01

1.4 | 2011-10-02
2.3 | 2011-10-02
-----------------
3.7 | 2011-10-02

5.6 | 2011-10-03
```