# GET top 3 result for each game for user in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is I need to return the list of each 'game_id' where the 'user_id' is in the top three of 'score' and his position.
My mysql table is as follows:

```
pk_hiscore_id
game_id
user_id
score
```

How would I do this?

Comment: This can be done by querying the database with aggregation functions, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort and add my database record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050213/how-to-sort-and-add-my-database-record)

Comment: What is connection between top three of the score and user_id ? Don't you want to return top three results ( sort them ASC and LIMIT 0,3 )

Answer (score 0):

Use this query and `mysql_fetch_assoc` the result:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

Then, loop through the resulting array like this:

```
// Assume that $array is the array you loaded the query result into.

for ($position = 1; $position <= 3; $position ++)
{
    $game_id = $array[$i-1]["game_id"];

    echo "Game ID: " . $game_id . "\n";
    echo "User Position: " . $position;
}
```

Unless I am understanding you incorrectly, that should give you the information you want.